Android Studio: UTF-8 encoding on Run window
In Android Studio on Windows11, I have a simple kotlin code, just: println("αβγδ"). The Greek characters appear in the Run window of Android Studio (i.e. console) as garbage (╬▒╬▓╬).
I believe it has to do with the encoding of command prompt in windows11, which is by default set to "Active code page:437" and not to "Active code page:65001".

I solved it! It is the default Active code page. I had to change it to: Active code page:65001.
I Checked the box for Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support in Control Panel > Region Settings > System Locale > Administrative tab > Change system locale... > Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support >OK.
